# How do I skip the opening trailer?

Tags: dogfight-1942

The trailer that starts every time I open Dogfight 1942 is *VERY* annoying.  How do I disable it or skip it?

Comment: If that works for you, please post it in the answer area when you can.

Answer (score 1):

To skip it, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (default key) twice. I don't know how to disable it though.